database TwoSampleMR is corrupt
I'm trying to load the TwoSampleMR package in R but every time I try to either load it or use a function from the package it says this:
Error in fetch(key) :
lazy-load database '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-x86_64/Resources/library/TwoSampleMR/help/TwoSampleMR.rdb' is corrupt
I've tried everything, I need to perform two sample MR for my dissertation so help would be so appreciated.
